# I have referenced the Libraries, but built dlls don't output to bin

Tags: c#, build, compilation

So I've had this problem for a little while now and looking at all the answers, I can't seem to fix it. My problem is this:

Upon deleting the folders in my Bin directory...

- A heap load of errors (are you missing an assembly or reference for ...EVERYTHING?)

So I Remove and add references, the problem still arises.

I'm starting to question my own sanity here. Am I mistaken in thinking that the release/debug folders should fill up with dlls when building?

**Attempted fixes**

- Checked hint paths, they are correct.
- Did the old "untick retick the build checkbox" trick in the Solution Properties page.
- Set Copy Local to True
- Crossed my fingers and prayed really hard.

Currently to prevent this problem from occurring I'm having to create a new empty project build that project with the same version references and copy the compiled dlls over! Someone save me!

Comment: try setting copyLocal to true on the dlls you have referenced in properties

Comment: Copy Local is set to true on the references :(

Comment: Check that the referenced library have the same target framework

Comment: Giving that a try now

Answer (score 0):

So after some prompting in the right direction by NDJ and bdn02, I found the problem:

My previous attempts to fix a specific dll were falling on death ears because the problem was with a different dll that all other dlls depended on.

When setting copy local to true I didn't realise it was being set to false the moment I came off the properties pane (Really it should prompt the user by informing them it can't set copy local to true, rather then silently change a users' input... But w/e). this made me curious, I compared the properties pane to the empty solution with the same reference and it turns out the "Path" attribute was missing from the property.

There are two ways to fix this, open your csproj in a notepad, find the reference and update the hint path, or uninstall and re install it... Reference problems can be a real pain.

[image: Screencap showing reference properties window with path attribute set]